# Passport Local Strategy is not working to retrieve the specific user data, while it gives the first user data from the table

Tags: authentication, serialization, deserialization, passport-local

I'm using Passport Local Strategy to authenticate a specific user from the user table and then get that user data to view:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ where: { username } })
      .then(function (user) {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false);
        }
        else {
          if (user.password != password) {
            return done(null, false);
          }
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (username, done) {
  User
    .find({ username: username })
    .then(function (user) {
      done(null, user);
    });
});
```

Getting `isAuthenticated` from passport local and passing it to the index route:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Title',
    isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated(),
    user: req.user
  });
});
```

Login routes:

```
router.get('/login', function (req, res) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Sign in' });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

But, when a user login, it authenticates the user and takes it to the index page, but it shows the first user name from the database table in the index page welcome message. It does not show the current user name.

Here is the index page:

```
extends layout

block content

  h1(id='title')= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  if !isAuthenticated
    a(href="login") Sign in
    p
    a(href="signup") Create an account
  else 
    p Welcome #{user.username}  
    a(href="Logout") Logout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `User.find({ username: username })` to `User.find({ where: {username: username} })` in the `deserializeUser` function.

Comment: I updated the `deserializeUser` function by adding `where` before `{username: username}` and it worked!